# Todo list на айфоне работает не корректно. Ломается верстка, не работает скрипт

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, crossbrowsertesting

Написала небольшой Todo list. На компе работает норм, на андроид норм. На айфоне вкладка карты сыпется верстка. Там вращающиеся карточки, на айфоне одновременно видно и переднюю и заднюю часть карты, когда начинаю писать что либо, то записывает не в передний, а в задний инпут и отображает надпись зеркально. Не срабатывает функция добавления картинки. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

```
<div class="col">
                    <div class="card style-element">
                        <div class="front">
                            <form class="upload-container" method="POST" action="#" data-img='0'>
                                <img class="upload-image" src="./img/images.png">
                                <div>
                                    <input id="file-input-1" class="file-input" type="file" name="file" multiple>
                                    <label for="file-input-1">Выберите файл</label>
                                    <span>или перетащите его сюда</span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <input class="card-text" placeholder="&#9998">
                                <button class="btn-card-text" data-index="0">ok</button>
                                <p class="out-front"></p>
                                <div class="img-position">
                                    <img src="./img/down.png" alt="#" class="download" data-down="0">
                                    <img src="./img/repost.png" alt="#" class="repost">
                                    <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#" class="delete-card" data-del="0">
                                    <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow-card">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <input type="text" class="back-text" placeholder="&#9998">
                            <button class="btn-card-back" data-back="0">ok</button>
                            <p class="out"></p>
                            <img src="./img/delete.png" alt="#" class="delete-back" data-delBack="0">
                            <img src="./img/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow-card back-arrow">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

.front{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   
}
.front, .back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: 2s;
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 0;
}

.front-rotate  {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back-rotate{
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
.upload-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 360px;
    height: 300px;
    outline: 2px dashed #5d5d5d;
    outline-offset: -12px;
    background-color: #e0f2f7;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: #1f3c44;
}

.upload-image {
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    user-select: none;
}
.upload-container label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-container label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.upload-container div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.upload-container input[type=file] {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
}
.upload-container input[type=file]:focus + label {  
    outline: 1px solid #0078d7;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
.img-new{
    width: 360px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.img-position img{   
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 5px 30px 5px 15px;
}
.card-text, .back-text{
    width: 88%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.btn-card-text, .btn-card-back{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
    background:#f8f9fa;
}
.back-arrow{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    float: right;
    margin: 35% 5% 0 0;
}
.out-front{   
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.out{
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.delete-back{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    margin: 35% 5% 0 5%;
}

// download file input
document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(d => {

    d.addEventListener('click', function () {
        d.parentElement.querySelector('input').focus();
    });
});


document.querySelectorAll('.file-input').forEach(d => {

    d.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (document.querySelector('#language').value == 'rus') {
            alert('Если вы хотите распечатать карточку в PDF формате ваша картинка должна быть следующих форматов: PNG, JPG, SVG.');
        };
        if (document.querySelector('#language').value == 'eng') {
            alert('If you want to print the card in PDF format, your picture must be in the following formats: PNG, JPG, SVG.');
        };
        if (document.querySelector('#language').value == 'ukr') {
            alert('Якщо ви хочете роздрукувати картку в PDF форматі ваша картинка повинна бути наступних форматах: PNG, JPG, SVG.');
        };
        let form_file = this.closest('.upload-container');
        const fileList = d.files;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            const img = form_file.querySelector('.upload-image');

            if (img) {
                const indexImg = +form_file.getAttribute('data-img');
                if (!inputValues[indexImg]) {
                    inputValues[indexImg] = { text: '', img: reader.result };
                }
                else {
                    inputValues[indexImg].img = reader.result;
                }

                localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(inputValues));
                img.setAttribute('src', reader.result);
            }
            img.classList.remove('upload-image');
            img.classList.add('img-new');
            form_file.querySelector('.upload-container label').classList.add('hide');
            form_file.querySelector('.upload-container span').classList.add('hide');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: По верстке я нашла, на айфоне почему то не работает backface-visibility: hidden; хотя на сайте Can I use, указано, что это свойство поддерживается браузером сафари и хромом, на айфоне. Но я не знаю, какой костыль применить, чтобы на афоне это заработало. А почему не работает функция добавления картинок,  я понять так и не смогла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С проблемой верстки разобралась таким образом:

```
.style-element{
    border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

добавила родительскому элементу -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;, так же расставила везде префиксы  -webkit.

```
.front, .back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: 2s;
}
```

Вот так сработало на айфоне корректно.
С добавление картинок разобралась частично, если сфотографировать, то фото добавляется отлично, если загружать из галереи, фото не грузится. Этот баг есть только на айфнах. Дальше буду разбираться. Если выясню, напишу сюда.